# Unity3D Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.

Tags: android, unity3d

hace varios días que me encontré con este error de compilación con un SDK Android propio que he creado.
El mismo, funciona sobre la versión 5 de Unity, pero no en la 4.x

Ya vi muchas alternativas sobre updatear el SDK Manager, etc.

Luego de varias pruebas, llegué a la conclusión de que no carga el archivo .aar, es algo de la versión 4.x de por sí.

Vi algunas referencias sobre cómo hacer que Unity pueda leer la classes de jar, pero la verdad que nada concreto.

Alguno tiene idea cómo puedo solucionar que lea la librería de java?

Desde ya muchas gracias, adjunto el error.

Saludos!

```
`Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Users\ppalma\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/ppalma/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[
AndroidManifest.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/XplayTheme').`
```

Comment: Buen día encontré esta pregunta la cual no tenía respuesta, imagino ya solucionaste el problema, de cualquier forma agrego la respuesta, saludos!.

Answer (score 0):

El archivo [.aar](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format), es un archivo que incluye los recursos, archivos dentro del folder `/res` de tu proyecto tales como drawables, layouts, etc.

El mensaje de error refiere a que existe un problema al empaquetarlos y este es el problema:

> stderr[ AndroidManifest.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that
>   matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/XplayTheme').`

**El problema es que en tu proyecto se esta haciendo referencia a un estilo `XplayTheme`
el cual no existe**, lo puedes verificar en el archivo:

```
/res/values/styles.xml
```

Debes tener algo similar a :

```
<resources>

    <style name="XplayTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     ...
     ...
     ...
    </style>

</resources>
```